# Generate Date Of Birth from ID number for people born after 2000

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a function to generate/ populate date of birth for ID numbers of people born after 2000.

This is my code right now, but it doesn't extend to after 2000

```
   var Year = idNumber.substring(0, 2);
   var Month = idNumber.substring(2, 4)
   var Day = idNumber.substring(4, 6)
   var dob = '19' + Year + '/' + Month + '/' + Day;
```

How can I modify this to accommodate > 2000?

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527), if you have a problem, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read the ['How to Ask a good question' guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527)

Comment: Thank you for updating the question with your code, although there's no enough of it (presumably that's part of a loop? What is `idNumber`?) Also what you're attempting to do still doesn't make sense. Are you trying to get a list of every possible date since 01/01/2000?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan given an id, eg 891231 convert to dob, eg 31/12/1989

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan another example 031219 should convert to 19/12/2003

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usual 2 digit year handling is to pick a cut-off date.  You could use this year's date +1 (19) for DOBs but you'll always get a problem with people over 99 years old.

```js
   

function getDob(idNumber) {
   var Year = idNumber.substring(0, 2);
   var Month = idNumber.substring(2, 4)
   var Day = idNumber.substring(4, 6)
   
   var cutoff = (new Date()).getFullYear() - 2000
   
   var dob = (Year > cutoff ? '19' : '20') + Year + '/' + Month + '/' + Day;
   
   return dob;
}

console.log(getDob("050505"));
console.log(getDob("180227"));
console.log(getDob("891231"));
console.log(getDob("000101"));
```

Comment: An alternative is to have the ID be 7 digits, eg 1050505 with the 105 being number of years since 1900.  It depends on the format of your ID.  (or just make it 8 digits and include the year in full).

Comment: Thank you, I am happy to mark the above as an answer, it does achieve what I want.

Answer (score -2):

```js
 class NationalData{
    BirthDate:Date=new Date()
    Day:number=0
    Month:number=0
    Year:number=0
    ErrorDate:boolean=false
    constructor(nationalNo:string){
        var c = nationalNo.substr(0,1)=='2'?'19':'20',
            y=c+nationalNo.substr(1,2),
            m=nationalNo.substr(3,2),
            d=nationalNo.substr(5,2);
        this.Day=Number(d)
        this.Month=Number(m)
        this.Year=Number(y)
        this.BirthDate=new Date(this.Year,this.Month,this.Day)
        this.ErrorDate=((this.Month>12 || this.Month<1) 
        || (this.Year%4==0 && this.Month==2 && this.Day>29 || this.Year%4!=0 && this.Month==2 && this.Day>28) 
        || ((this.Month==1 || this.Month==3 || this.Month==5 || this.Month==7 || this.Month==8 || this.Month==10 || this.Month==12) && this.Day>31)
        || ((this.Month==4 || this.Month==5 || this.Month==9 || this.Month==11) && this.Day>30)
        || (this.Day<1))
     
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Your code does not look like common JS code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).